# Javascript functions within self-executed block not accesible. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, function, scope

I have a simple index.html file with some dragable images. My JS file looks like this:

```
    function drop(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

    function drag(ev){
      ev.dataTransfer.setData('text',ev.target.id);
    }
```

That works perfectly fine. But, as I learned, it's good practice to write your code within a self-executed block.

So, I moved my two functions:

```
    (function(){

      function drop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      }

      function drag(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('text',ev.target.id);
      }

    })();
```

And now, when dragging the images around, the functions appear to be 'undefined'. They're probably newbie questions but:

- Can I keep my functions in the block scope and still use them on the HTML like `<div id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)">...</div>`?
- If not, why?

Comment: Try to take a look at closure.Anyway the inner function will be just parsed , but it wont be executed unless u call it

Comment: it's a scope issue. if you want those functions to be global, `window.drop=function(ev){ ...` etc

Comment: Am I not calling it from the HTML tag? `<div id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)">...</div>`

Comment: yes, so it needs to be global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of enclosing stuff into IIFEs is to isolate them and not pollute the global environment with unnecessaries. For example,

```
var counter = (function() {
  var current = 0;
  function getCurrentAndIncrement() {
    return current++;
  };
  return getCurrentAndIncrement;
})();

counter()
// 0
counter()
// 1
current
// ReferenceError: current is not defined
```

We hide what should be private, and expose what should be public.

You hid everything - then the fact that it is inaccessible should not be a surprise.

Finally, `<div id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)">...</div>` is a bad practice. Binding event listeners from JavaScript is much better, if a bit more complicated. Do just this:

```
<div id="div0">...</div>
```

then in JavaScript,

```
var div0 = document.getElementById('div0');
div0.addEventListener('drop', myHandler);
```

and this can, indeed, be stuffed into an IIFE. Whatever you refer to from HTML (as in your `drop` function) needs to be in global scope, or the browser will not be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *scope*. The variables and functions defined within a function are only accessible within that function. In your first example, you're defining them globally; in your second example, they're inside a function.

> Can I keep my functions in the block scope and still use them on the HTML like `<div id="div0" ondrop="drop(event)">...</div>`?

To use functions from old-fashioned `onxyz` attribute handlers, they have to be *globals*. You can make your functions globals by assigning them to properties on the global object, which you can access as `window` on browsers:

```
(function() {

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id);
    }

    window.drop = drop;
    window.drag = drag;

})();
```

...but ideally, it's better *not* to create globals; the global namespace is *incredibly* crowded, adding to it just asks for conflicts. Instead, use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, `attachEvent`) instead of `onxyz` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The inner function wont be executed. Here comes the beauty of closure make js objects private & public . This code may serve your purpose

```
var demoFunction =(function(){
    function _drop(ev){
        alert("Helo");
          _drag();
      }
    function _drag(ev){
       alert("Hello1");
      }
    _drop();

   return{
         drop :_drop,
         drag:_drag    
    }
})();
```

You can also call this drop and drag from other functions by demoFunction.drop & so on.Hope this is helpful for you

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m5okwtj/)